# Separate unit and integration test with Jacoco and Sonar

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, sonarqube, jacoco

I took the `combined-ut-it-multimodule-maven-jacoco` [example](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/code-coverage/combined%20ut-it/combined-ut-it-multimodule-maven-jacoco) from `Sonar github`. Basically the example has one module with a unit test, and another module with an integration test. The coverage results are 40% by UT and 50% by IT for an overall coverage of 80%.

Then I added a new unit test for the uncovered code in the `app` module:

```
package example;

import org.junit.Test;

public class HelloWorldAnotherUnitTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        new HelloWorld().notCovered();
    }

}
```

The coverage results are 60% by UT, 50% by IT for an overall coverage of 100%. So far so good.

The I switched that test from `app` to the `app-it` module and the coverage results are 40% by UT, 70% by IT for an overall coverage of 100%. Here I was expecting the same result as the previous coverage.

So it seems that the coverage for a specific module can be either unit or integration. Is that a bug?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get what the problem is... If you move a test case from UTs to ITs, then this looks normal that the UT coverage decreases while the IT coverage increases...

Comment: The test is still a UT but I just put it in `app-it` instead of `app`.

Comment: So it's not considered as an UT but an IT, what's the problem?

Comment: The `HelloWorldAnotherUnitTest` is a UT, so its coverage should be counted toward UT coverage and not IT coverage as it is right now.

Comment: What tells is a JUnit/TestNG test class is a UT or an IT is the location where you place it, not what is done in the class. When you put it in "app-it", you clearly indicate that this is an IT, not a UT.

Comment: What if in a module you have both UT and IT? It seems that the coverage will be counted toward integration coverage.